# FactoryGirl: undefined method `paypal' for class `Factory'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Stupid question:
I have a factory for Payment model

```
   Factory.define :payment do |f|
     ...
     f.method 'paypal'
     ...
   end
```

This gives me an error:

> undefined method  `paypal' for class `Factory'

I think the problem is the [method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001038) method in Ruby's class [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html).

Is there any way to use 'method' as attribute in factories with FactoryGirl?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly encourage you to avoid that attribute name. Rename the column in your database. You are likely going to fall into the same issue in several others cases.

Honestly, I don't know any way to solve this. You can use the `after_create` callback, but it's definitely not a final solution.

Comment: Yes, I think I will rename it as "payment_method". The reason for this attribute name was that "payment.method" reads definitely better than "payment.payment_method". Thank you.